# Event LIstener before Dark Mode Function

Tags: typescript, event-listener, darkmode

Shure quite simple but it struggles me. I'm asked to put a Dark Mode Button in my `Nav-Bar`, which turns Dark Mode on and off.

I found a solution for that, but now I have to implement it into the `EventListener` that looks like this:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded" , () => {
  
//insert your code here

});
```

My Script looks like this:

```js
    function DarkModeFunktion() {
        var element = document.body;
        element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
    };

//works just fine
```

I put my code into the given Space and it looked like this:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded" , () => {
  
function DarkModeFunktion() {
        var element = document.body;
        element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
    };

});

//does nothing
```

As I just started learning how to code I realy could use some help here. The given explanations are poorely giving any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't call function DarkModeFunktion in event handler method

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded" , () => {
    //defintion
    function DarkModeFunktion() {
           var element = document.body;
            element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
        };

    }
    //you don't call it
);
```

First solution - just call defined function:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded" , () => {
    //defintion
    function DarkModeFunktion() {
           const element = document.body;
           element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
        };

    }
    DarkModeFunktion()
);
```

Two - define it outside and call it (preferred):

```js
function DarkModeFunktion() {
        const element = document.body;
        element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
    };
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded" , () => {DarkModeFunktion());
//or
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded" , DarkModeFunktion);
```

Three - just define your code in handler assinge:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded" , () => {
   const element = document.body;
   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
);
```

EDIT.

What's more as point @Tom Bailey you can't call function DarkModeFunktion from outside events (button links etc...) because you defined in scope of DOMContentLoaded handler function so it doesn't' live in global scope so you can't access it.

Comment: The OP wants a button to toggle dark-mode. This code, while it does work, is being fired on page load which is not the desired functionality.

Comment: I don't' believe that is fired any ever. it can't

Comment: See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event - "The DOMContentLoaded event fires when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading."

Comment: I know it. But he toggle class on dom element witch is loaded so is not a problem, browser will apply corect styles to this class when stylesheet will loads.

Comment: Yes, but you don't want to apply dark-mode styles when the page loads. You want the dark-mode styles to be applied when the user presses a button. As OP requested "I'm asked to put a Dark Mode Button in my Nav-Bar, w[h]ich turns Dark Mode on and off.". OP posted the function, and then said that it didn't work when they put it inside the event handler. My recommendation is that they don't put it inside this event handler, thus the function will be in global scope when it is called by the button's `onclick` event.

Comment: ok. i know what is solution. but i try to explain why it doesn't worked for him.It doesn't work because1. he dont' call defined function 2. he define it in closed scope so he cant access it outside this scope.  (From his question you can deduct that if first version - not scoped - works probably he fired it from some event - button link what ever)

Comment: Yes, there's a button link in index.html, wich fires it.
Thanks for all the Answers, I will discuss those later with my teammates and hope we'll get this running :)

Answer (score 0):

The event you are listening to, "DOMContentLoaded", fires when the page loads. You actually want to call your function on the 'button pressed' event. You can do this quite easily as follows in your HTML:

```
<button onclick="DarkModeFunktion()">Toggle Dark Mode</button>
```

I would also recommend renaming your function to `ToggleDarkMode` to make it really clear what it does.